# Paylater receipt showing strange characters

Tags: civimember, receipts

I've a membership subscription page with a single payment option - pay later.
The setup has a confirmation page and the receipt page upon confirmation.
On the receipt page, pay later instructions are shown but strange characters appear over the paragraphs, as you can see on the below image:

[image: Pay later instructions on receipt page]

These instructions are also shown on previous pages (confirmation for example) without any error. Is this a bullet-related issue as it only happens on paragraphs that have them? if not, is there any way to change any setting to prevent this behaviour?

Best regards
João